# Select related on 3 tables in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, select, orm

I need some help to perform a select_related in Django framework.
My model is:

```
models.py

class Richiesta(models.Model):
    # TIPOLOGIE_DISPOSITIVO can be = BK or SC
    codice = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    ufficio_registrazione = models.ForeignKey(UfficioRegistrazione, null=True, blank=False)
    tipologia = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, choices=TIPOLOGIE_DISPOSITIVO, default=TIPOLOGIE_DISPOSITIVO[0][0])
    tipo = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, choices=TIPO_CHOICES, default=TIPO_PRIMO_RILASCIO)
    data_produzione = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class UfficioRegistrazione(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, null=False, blank=False)

class Cliente(models.Model):
    # provider can be = 1 or 2
    denominazione = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    codice_cliente = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False, db_index=True)
    provider = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, choices=PROVIDER_CHOICES)
```

and there is the raw sql query I need to perform with Django ORM:

```
select cms_richiesta.id, cms_richiesta.tipologia, cms_richiesta.data_produzione, 
cms_richiesta.ufficio_registrazione_id, cms_ufficioregistrazione.id, 
cms_ufficioregistrazione.cliente_id, cms_cliente.id, cms_cliente.provider, 
cms_cliente.denominazione, cms_cliente.codice_cliente
from cms_richiesta INNER JOIN cms_ufficioregistrazione on 
cms_richiesta.ufficio_registrazione_id=cms_ufficioregistrazione.id
INNER JOIN cms_cliente on cms_ufficioregistrazione.cliente_id = 
cms_cliente.id where data_produzione>'2011-01-01' and data_produzione<'2017- 
12-31' and cms_cliente.provider = 2 and cms_richiesta.tipologia='BK'
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
Richiesta.objects.filter(ufficio_registrazione__cliente__provider=2,tipologia='BK')
```

and rest filter can be added like that

Answer (score 1):

You can process this as:

```
from datetime import datetime

Richiesta.objects.select_related(
    'ufficio_registrazione',
    'ufficio_registrazione__cliente',
).filter(
    data_produzione__range=(datetime(2011, 1, 1), datetime(2017, 12, 30)),
    ufficio_registrazione__cliente__provider=2,
    tipologia='BK',
)
```

Typically the `.select_related(..)` is here *not* necessary, since we perform these `JOIN`s already at the filtering part, but typically it is better to be explicit than implicit (especially in case you would later omit a condition, and still want these related models to be fetched).

It will retrieve `Richiesta` objects, but with related models already loaded.

You probably meant `<= '2017-12-31'` in which case the upper bound of the date range needs to be incremented as well.

Answer (score 0):

I dont want paste and copy other answer, but you can use .values() to extract only the columns that you want to work, if you think this is really necessary, because in template you will show only the data that you want

```
richiesta.values('tipologia', 'data_produzione'...) # when richiesta is the queryset
```